# Can not connect to network with Maven command through proxy with STS 3.7.0+

Tags: eclipse, maven, proxy, m2e, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to use Spring Tool Suite(STS) 3.7.2 through a proxy network but ran into a error below when Maven command is executed.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project todo: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 -> org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6 -> org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 -> junit:junit:jar:3.8.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:3.8.1: Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:pom:3.8.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to authenticate with proxy -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project todo: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 -> org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6 -> org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 -> junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 -> org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6 -> org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 -> junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 -> org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6 -> org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 -> junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:422)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:385)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:231)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:102)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 -> org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6 -> org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 -> junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:202)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:302)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:pom:3.8.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to authenticate with proxy
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:287)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:pom:3.8.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to authenticate with proxy
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:895)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:1)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:673)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.makeTunnel(Connection.java:426)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:229)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:159)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:175)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:120)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:330)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:319)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:271)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:228)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:199)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
    at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.execute(OkHttpAetherClient.java:154)
    at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.get(OkHttpAetherClient.java:100)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.resumableGet(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:600)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:453)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:304)
    ... 52 more
```

It seems like there is a problem when connecting to a Maven's central repository.
So I checked my network configuration of STS, proxy configuration of STS, proxy configuration of ~HOME/.m2/setting.xml, but can't see any problems with any of it.

I can use the network browser inside STS and show websites such as google.com  and of course https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 using proxy network, so I'm guessing the configs are not the problem.

I tried the previous version of STS, got the same problem with 3.7.1 and 3.7.0, but finally succeeded using 3.6.4.

Has anyone else faced the same problem?

Or am I missing some config setting with my STS??

Comment: You have a problem with your proxy: `: Failed to authenticate with proxy -> ` which means you need to configure your proxy access in your settings.xml correctly...But i think you have a repository manager inside your company so you should use that instead...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's no problem with my settings.xml since I can use maven command in my local. I ran into this problem only by using STS 3.7.0～3.7.2.

Comment: I am wondering why this works in Eclipse but not STS (since the Maven support that files in the stack trace above is m2e from Eclipse, nothing special to STS). However, lets try to find out what exactly is causing this different behavior. What version of Eclipse did you use to test this? What exact version of m2e did you have installed in Eclipse? And which version of m2e in STS? There must be something that is causing this issue with the proxy authentication.

Comment: Sorry, I had it wrong, I thought it worked with Eclipse 4.5 but it didn't(guess my local repository was not working as I expected...). I checked both Eclipse 4.5.0 and 4.5.1 but both failed with the maven command. So now I only have STS3.6.4 to success, and m2e plugin version with the success is 1.5.x, but the version with failure is 1.6.x.

Answer (score 2):

the problem was a bug in aether-connector-okhttp.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=477893

so I tried m2e 1.7.0, the latest milestone build(1.7.0.20160202-2119), and got STS 3.7.2 working fine.